# Examples of nilpotent connected locally compact groups which are not Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I am looking for examples of nilpotent connected (or at least almost connected) locally compact groups which are not Lie groups. Do you know of such examples ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The infinite product ${\mathbb S}^1 \times {\mathbb S}^1 \times ...$ satisfies this requirement. It is abelian, compact and connected, but it is not a Lie group because it has an infinite, strictly increasing chain of connected, closed subgroups.